# Variable declaration in C - parser flex/bison

Tags: c, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I only start with flex and bison.
I wrote a parser, it should recognize variable declarations in C

e.g.
`int a; float b3; char * aaa;`.

At the output, it should write a valid declaration and 'ok'.
It compiles, but doesn't show 'ok' at the output.
I don't know if I use tokens well. How should I improve it?

my file.l

```
alpha   [a-zA-Z]
digit   [0-9]

%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include "cw22.tab.h"

%}

%%

"int"       { printf("int") ; } //return INT ;
"float"     { printf("float") ; } //return FLOAT ;
"char"      { printf("char") ; } //return CHAR ;
"char *"    { printf("char *") ; } //return CHAR_8 ;
";"     { printf(";") ; } //return SYM;

{alpha}({alpha}|{digit})*   { printf("%s", yytext) ; } //return ID;

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

my file.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

%}

%token ID
%token INT
%token FLOAT
%token CHAR
%token CHAR_8
%token SYM

%%

start   : TYPE ID SYM 
    ;

TYPE    : INT
    | FLOAT
    | CHAR
    | CHAR_8
    ;
%%

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    yyparse();
    printf("ok");
    return 0;
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "errorL %s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: I'm not a parser expert, but I suspect the problem may be that `char *` is two tokens, not a single token.

Comment: Why are the `return` statements commented out?

Comment: You never return any tokens from your lexer, so the parser never gets anything to parse.

Comment: When I returned the token, the parser did not compile... Where should I return it?

Comment: The `return`s need to be inside the curly-{}, but right where you have them.

Comment: Ok, so I changed returns, the praser compiles but the parser displays empty lines and the wrong part of the declaration. What should I change to get the correct declarations from the test file?